# Delete all usages of an actionlistener

Tags: java, actionlistener

Is there any way to delete an action listener off all components that have it attached?

Something like: `Action.removeFromAll();`

I have attached this Action to several different buttons and when any button is pushed it should no longer be possible to activate this action. So in the action performed of this action I want to delete it from all the buttons. Is this possible or will I just have to loop through all the buttons?

Comment: Action supports central control of a shared action.  It has a setEnabled(boolean) method that can be used to enable or disable the action.

Comment: @ditkin isn't that for the component? That will disable the button completely won't it? The button will still be used for other actions. I just want to disable this particular one

Comment: are you refractoring your code?

Comment: @Blip what do you mean? Im writing new code

Comment: If you are writing a new code, then why are you adding the `actionEvent` to the components that do not require to perform the action?

Comment: @Blip I don't understand. I have a bunch of buttons with this action listener `Action` But I want the action listener to be removed after one of the buttons are clicked. Any button can be clicked but they will all do the same action which should only ever be done once by any button

Answer (score 1):

An easier work around would be to create an instance variable `boolean shouldPerformAction = true` on  the action listener. And when you get the button pushed action, you set it to `false`. And in the `actionPerformed()` method, you check if the `shouldPerformAction` is false and return without doing any action.

Comment: thats a good idea too, If instead of doing: `addActionlistener(new Action)`
I do: `Action a = new Action()` and then add `a` as the action listener to all the buttons can I have a field in the Action class? will they all share it?